# About reportlab

Tags: javascript, pdf, reportlab

I have a problem with a with my ReportLab. I want to create PDFs with data coming from my javascript code with Chinese or any other non-Roman letters in it. I tried using different techniques in unicode but it still appears as Black boxes in the PDF. I have something in my js like these and I want to make the text "Warranty ....." to chinese or something.

```
content.find('#wtc')
                   .html('<br/><span style="font-size:20px;color:rgb(9,79,163);"> Warranty General Terms and Conditions</span>');
```

When it is in roman characters, its perfectly fine. However, if i insert something like *[&]#21512;* it doesn't show as it should be which is like this >> 合

Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance!

PS, please bear with me. I'm new here as well as in reportlab.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add to reportlab fonts that support the encoding you want?
for example:

```
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Times-Italic', 'timesi.ttf', 'UTF-8'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Times-BoldItalic', 'timesbi.ttf', 'UTF-8'))
from reportlab.lib.fonts import addMapping
addMapping('Times', 0, 0, 'Times')    #normal
addMapping('Times', 0, 1, 'Times-Italic')    #italic
```

Place this fonts in to \site-packages\reportlab\fonts